# give an example of a countable dense subset of $C[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Give an example of a countable dense subset of $C[0,1]$.

I think the set of all rational polynomials defined on $[0,1]$ will do.

My attempt: Let $A$ be the set of all rational polynomials defined on $[0,1]$. Clearly $A\subset C[0,1]$, pick any $f\in C[0,1]$ and consider a ball $B_{\epsilon}(f)$ for $\epsilon>0$. By Stone Weierstrass theorem $\exists$ polynomial $P$ such that $P \in B_{\epsilon}(f)$, in fact we can choose rational polynomial, so $B_{\epsilon}(f) \cap A \neq \phi ,\ \forall \ \epsilon>0$. Therefore $cl(A) = C[0,1]$

Will this work?

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much the idea.

Comment: How do you justify the assertion “in fact we can choose rational polynomial”?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I got the idea from here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2899988/601199